# Multiple queries in database depending on parameter without loops

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database and a Perl script like this

```
sub reassign_minions {
    my $self = shift;
    my @users = $self->get_userids_of_minions();

    my $sth = $self->dbh->prepare(qq{update users set reports_to = ? where userid = ?});
    $sth->execute($self->reports_to, $user);
    $sth->finish;
}
```

`@users` is suppose to hold an array of multiple user IDs (integers). For each user ID it returns I want to update the `reports_to` column with a variable, but I'm not sure how to query multiple variables.

If it was just one it would be easy, because I can just set the variable parameter into something like `$userid` like what I have above. But since the number of IDs that can be passed in are not fixed I'm not sure what to do.

I was also told that there is a way to do this without the use of loops as I originally had a `for` loop.

Comment: Is this a plain copy-paste from your real code? Note that your statement `$self->dbh>prepare(qq{update users set reports_to = ? where userid = ?})` is wrong. It is doing `$self->dbh` and then `prepare(qq{update users set reports_to = ? where userid = ?})` and testing whether the return value from the former is greater than that from the latter.

Comment: Oh right, that was a typo. It should of been a `->` after the `dbh` so `dbh->prepare` instead of `dbh>prepare`

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought you meant, but *please* post real code and not something you've edited. That way lies insanity as we will find bugs that don't exist!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IN` with placeholders

```
sub reassign_minions {
    my $self = shift;
    my @users = $self->get_userids_of_minions();

    my $in = join ',', ('?') x @users;
    my $sth = $self->dbh->prepare(qq{update users set reports_to = ? where userid IN ($in)});
    $sth->execute($self->reports_to, @users) or die $self->dbh->errstr;;
    $sth->finish;
}
```

Comment: I like that. Does it really work? I would expect it to do `WHERE userid IN ($users[0])`

Comment: I haven't used PostgreSQL lately, but yep, it works in MySQL and SQLite.

Comment: Can you explain the first line `my $in = join ',', '?' x @users;` to me. I dont really get whats going on and shouldnt 'IN' take in an array instead? Why do you only pass in the variable $in

Comment: Hang on I'm confused. You're *interpolating* the `join` string but also passing the array as a parameter. I guess you meant `$sth->execute($self->reports_to)`?

Comment: I had a bug, I was missing the parenthesis around my `('?')`.  Now the `$in` variable will evaluate to `?,?,?,?` if there are 4 elements in `@users`.

Comment: Yep, my bad.  Might have been a while since I've had to create a manual SQL statement, but I know it works ... when I don't introduce a bug :)

Comment: Manual as opposed to ... do you use `DBIx::Class`?

Comment: Can you break down `my $in = join ',', ('?') x @users;`. I assume its going through `@users` and looking for ',' and then setting a '?' for each variable in the array but I don't understand the exact functionality of those operands and what the 'x' is at the end before `@users`

Comment: @Borodin That's the best one I know of, but in the past I've used my own hand-rolled [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) which I created before `DBIx::Class` and `Moose` existed.  I'm moving to the latter two though.

Comment: @user3767853 `x` is the [`repetition operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators).  It performs in both a list and scalar context.  In this case, it duplicates the list `('?')` a total of `scalar(@users)` times.  Which are then joined with a comma into the string `$in`.

Comment: `my $in = join ',', map {'?'} @users;` is a better alternative imo

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
my $sth = $self->dbh>prepare(qq{update users set reports_to = ? where userid = ?});
foreach my $user(@users) {
    $sth->execute($self->reports_to, $user);
}
$sth->finish;
```

Comment: The user originally said he had it in a loop but wants to avoid using a loop if he can, which is the origin of the question.  Your answer is perfectly valid and logical but goes directly against the problem being solved.